# Not checking a branch

Tags: git, branch, commit

I try running multiple times:

```
git checkout mygithub/master
```

Unfortunately it doesn't check out this branch:

```
git status
# Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

So what do I do to check out a branch and push commits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git clone git@github.com:myusername/myrepo.git
cd myrepo
git checkout master
```

then edit your files

```
git status
git add .
git commit
git push origin master
```

Comment: git checkout master seems to have fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately it doesn't check out this branch

The issue is actually that it *does* check out that branch (or rather, the commit at the head of that branch), but that's not what you want it to do.

Some background: when you add a remote (`github`) to your local repo, your local repo creates "remote branches" (`github/master`) for all of that remote's branches.  When you say `git checkout github/master`, you are telling git to take you off of any local branch and update your working copy to the state of the remote repo at that point in time.  You can only make commits on local branches, hence the problem.  See the docs on [`git checkout`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-checkout.html) for details.

By doing `git checkout master`, you are doing two things: first and most importantly, creating a local branch called `master` that by default is set up to track any remote branch with the same name it can find (hopefully `github/master` in this case), and then putting you on that branch and updating your working copy with its contents.  See the docs on [`git branch`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-branch.html) (since the first step is creating the branch) and [`git config`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-config.html) under `branch.autosetupmerge` for what's going on behind the scenes there.